# How to transfer a variable from main method class to another class?

Tags: java, class, variables

Okay... in my main class, I ask the user to enter an input int value.
Now I need to take this value to a different class to do some coding. How?

Code from main class:

```
neededValue = keyboard.nextInt();

object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy):
```

---

Code from a different method in a different class:

```
public void methodName(double xxxx, int yyyy) {

        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            xxxx = array[index].xxxx;
            if (xxxx > **neededValue**) {
                //some more code

            }

        }
    }
```

---

Lets say user input is 4, how can I transfer that "4" to other classes?

Comment: You pass it as a parameter.

Comment: or add a getter to your main class

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `neededValue` as argument

```
neededValue = keyboard.nextInt();   
object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy,neededValue):
```

Then in `methodName` function

```
public void methodName(double xxxx, int yyyy, int neededValue) {

    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        xxxx = array[index].xxxx;
        if (xxxx > **neededValue**) {
            //some more code
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

From main:

```
neededValue = keyboard.nextInt();

object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy, neededValue):
```

From the class:

```
public void methodName(double xxxx, int yyyy, int neededValue){
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        xxxx = array[index].xxxx;
        if (xxxx > **neededValue**) {
            //some more code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your another class method and pass the value from your main class.. same as below:

```
class A{
...
neededValue = keyboard.nextInt();

DifferentClass object = new DifferentClass();
object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy, neededValue):
...
}

class DifferentClass{
public void methodName(double xxxx, int yyyy, int neededValue) {
...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the `nextValue` variable to the method directly, like:

`object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy, nextValue)`

2. or you can declare a int variable in the class A of object:

   `int someValue;`

and set it by constructor or setter

```
object = new A(nextValue);
or object.setNextValue(nextValue)
```

then, your invoke `object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy)` will work with the 'someValue' field inside the object

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do it, few are listed below,

i) Create parameter in your method (explained in other solutions).

ii) Create a variable in your class with get/set methods in your class (explained in other solutions).

iii) Create a static variable in your class (explained below)

You can have a static variable in your class,

`private static int neededValue;`

And in your main, you can assign the value for it.

```
ClassName.neededValue = keyboard.nextInt();

object.methodName(xxxx, yyyy):
```

And you can use directly in your class method,

```
public void methodName(double xxxx, int yyyy){
int index;

for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    xxxx = array[index].xxxx;
    if (xxxx > ClassName.neededValue) {
        //some more code
    }
 }
}
```

Disclaimer: Know more about static keyword before using it.